Advanced Filtering
My goal here is to filter by a name only. The current filter shows every combination of every name. I would like to simplify this.


How would you like to simplify this?

I would like a single list of names to choose from instead of every combination with multiple names.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's not showing "every combination", only all the distinct values that are found in the column, in alphabetical order. This includes the entire strings as they are found in  "Assignee", not combinations.

Create a list of the unique names in the Assignee column. Then use that in a drop down that you can reference from either the Advanced Filter or the excel FILTER function to produce your desired results.

As I understand it, you are looking to filter the column where it contains a specific name anywhere in the combinations of names in the Assignee column.

Type the name you're looking for in the Search box of the filter pane. The list of items will be filtered to every item containing the text you've typed in the search box.
Click 'OK' to filter the table for all the rows matching the selected items.

